# Why is Microsoft Exchange Transport Log Search using 100% cpu and 3GB of memory?

Tags: exchange-2010

Our Exchange Server 2010 recently suffered an NDR attack which meant we had to delete the mail queue database and restart our machine.

Now though the Microsoft Exchange Transport Log Search runs at startup and almost immediately takes 90 - 100% cpu time and memory usage balloons for this one service until the machine grinds to a halt. So I have had to disable this service so that the machine is usable but do not know the consequences of this action.

It's Exchange 2010 SP1 with rollup 4 v2 applied.

Can anyone tell me why this may happen.

**Update**: I have disabled the service for over 3 weeks now and I have not seen any side effects. Can anyone tell me if this could cause a problem?

Comment: Have you disabled your AV? If that fixes it, you might check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332342.aspx

Comment: Disabled AV and still the same.